# Ubuntu 14.04: Audio doesnt work until I change the volume

Tags: 14.04, sound, pulseaudio, volume-control

I have this weird bug that *I think* I also had with 13.30, where I a movie or Spotify, it doesnt matter which application, and the audio wouldn't play at all. Of course my first reaction would be to increase the system audio volume, in case it was at 0%. Even thought that is not the case, I have noticed that when the system volume reaches around 80%, audio suddenly starts working.

After that point, I can put the volume back at its original lever, whatever that was, and it would play nicely. But everytime I start a new application, like Spotify, VLC or similar, I get over and over this error.

Is this a known bug? Is there a solution or workaround?

Comment: Same problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is quite likely to not work.**

First create a script in your home folder with this in it:

amixer -D pulse sset Master 80%+
amixer -D pulse sset Master 80%-

```
#!/bin/sh

amixer -D pulse sset Master 50%+
amixer -D pulse sset Master 50%-
```

The open terminal and execute the command:

`chmod +x volumeset.sh`

Finally, just to test it works, run the command `./volumeset.sh` in terminal and see if it fixes the sound. If it does, open `startup applications` then add in the command:

`./volumeset.sh`

To run it automatically at login.

Comment: Wow, that is kinda messy and hard to mantain. Is this a known bug?

Comment: Can't see that it is anywhere, but I seem to remember something similar on 12.04 on one of my machines.